# Is there a story in the Bible about a certain person named Cartaphilus?

Tags: verse-identification

Where is it located in the Bible about the man whom was cursed to walk the face of the earth forever? (I believe his name was Cartaphilus.)

Comment: It is not in Sacred Scriptures.

Comment: See [Wandering Jew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandering_Jew) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse search question.

Answer (score 6):

The Story of Cartaphilus or as more commonly known as the [Wandering Jew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandering_Jew) is simply a legend and cannot be found in any Bible Scriptures whatsoever.

In a nutshell the legend goes like this:

> [Cartaphilus](http://www.biblicalcyclopedia.com/C/cartaphilus-(or-cartophyllus).html) (or, Cartophyllus) in Christian legend, was a Roman soldier who was doorkeeper at the entrance to the palace of Pilate at the time of Our Lord's crucifixion. When Jesus was led out thence, and went too slow for Cartaphilus, the latter struck him with his hand, and mockingly said, "Faster, Jesus, faster; why tarriest thou?" But Jesus pitifully looked at him, and said, "I go, but thou shalt tarry until I come again!" In fulfillment of the Savior's prophecy, Cartaphilus still waits in tears and anxiety for the judgment, and only the Savior's own merciful prayer sustains him: "Father, forgive them, for they know not what they do." This is the basis, of the fable about the Wandering Jew (q.v.). See Meth. Quar. Rev. July, 1882.

Comment: It is also extremely loosely based on Matthew 16 v28 - there be some here who will not die.

Comment: Ty for your comnent!